# Forcing azurerm extension to wait until vm is deployed

Tags: terraform

I am running into an issue that is preventing my use of Terraform at the moment and wanted to see if anyone has seen the same behavior. I am using count to deploy multiple VM's along with a dsc extension for each VM.

Because I need the dsc extension to run on the first machine before running on the second machine, I attempted to use the depends_on property for the extension but due to the way I an using interpolation for machine naming, it fails due interpolation not being supported in depends_on.

Does anyone know a way around this? I have tested also tested pushing the machine names into a data resource but once again, I need the depends_on property to support interpolation.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "Server" {
  name = "${format("${var.customerProject}${var.environment}${var.machineAcronyms["Server"]}%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  location = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.Server_NIC.*.id, count.index)}"]
  vm_size = "${var.Server_Specs["ServerType"]}"
  count = "${var.Server_Specs["Number_of_Machines"]}"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "${var.Server_Specs["Image_Publisher"]}"
    offer = "${var.Server_Specs["Image_Offer"]}"
    sku = "${var.Server_Specs["Image_sku"]}"
    version = "${var.Server_Specs["Image_Version"]}"
  }

  plan {
    name = "${var.Server_Specs["Plan_Name"]}"
    publisher = "${var.Server_Specs["Plan_Publisher"]}"
    product = "${var.Server_Specs["Plan_Product"]}"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${format("${var.customerProject}${var.environment}${var.machineAcronyms["Server"]}%02d", count.index + 1)}"
    admin_username = "${var.AdminCredentials["Username"]}"
    admin_password = "${var.AdminCredentials["Password"]}"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {
    provision_vm_agent  = "true"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "Server_DSC" {
  name = "${format("${var.customerProject}${var.environment}${var.machineAcronyms["Server"]}%02d", count.index + 1)}-dsc"
  location = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${format("${var.customerProject}${var.environment}${var.machineAcronyms["Server"]}%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  publisher = "Microsoft.Powershell"
  type = "DSC"
  type_handler_version = "${var.dsc_extension}"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  depends_on = ["azurerm_storage_share.fileShare"]
  count = "${var.Server_Specs["Number_of_Machines"]}"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
  {
    "configuration": {
        "url": "${var.resourceStore["fileShareUrl"]}${var.resourceStore["dscArchiveName"]}${var.azureCredentials["storageKey"]}",
        "function": "contenthostingha",
        "script": "contenthostingha.ps1"
    },
    "configurationArguments": {
        "ExternalDNS": "${var.externalDNS}",
        "NumberOfMachines": "${var.Server_Specs["Number_of_Machines"]}",
        "AzureFileUrl": "azurerm_storage_share.fileShare.url",
        "AzureFileShareKey": "${azurerm_storage_account.storageAccount.secondary_access_key}"
    }
}

  SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
  {
    "configurationArguments": {}
  }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but you might duplicate the Server_DSC resource (e.g. `Server_DSC_0` and `Server_DSC_nth`), the _0 will use a fixed `"0"` instead of count and the number of instances should be lessen by 1, e.g using a local variable that subtract one to the original variable.